# querySelector method returns null

Tags: javascript, html

My code (simplified):

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body align="center">
<div id="container">
<h1>Title</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
const container = document.querySelector('#container');

for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
        const cellSize = 512 / 16;
        const cell = document.createElement('div');

        cell.style.width = cellSize + 'px';
        cell.style.height = cellSize + 'px';
        container.appendChild(cell);
    }
};
```

Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
```

What have I done wrong here? It might just be my browser (I'm using Chrome). Is it because the constants are being referenced inside the for loop?

Comment: Your code is executing before the document is ready, so the `#container` element doesn't exist yet. Try `console.log()` the `container`  to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your document is not ready yet. You need to wait for the document to be rendered before applying JavaScript to it.

Therefore you should call your script after the HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body align="center">
<div id="container">
<h1>Title</h1>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `getElementById()` instead to retrieve your `div`. Try this:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');

for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
        var cellSize = 512 / 16;
        var cell = document.createElement('div');

        cell.style.opacity = 0.0;
        cell.style.width = cellSize + 'px';
        cell.style.height = cellSize + 'px';
        container.appendChild(cell);
    }
};
```

Also make sure the script runs AFTER loading the html.